# ¿Cómo defino un destructor si en el constructor uso std::allocator?

Tags: c++, manejo-de-memoria, constructor

Tengo una clase donde he definido el siguiente constructor copia.

```
ArrayWrapper (const ArrayWrapper& other)
:_metadata(other._metadata)

{
    size_t sz=other._metadata.getSize();
    std::allocator<int> myBuffer;
    int * pBuffer=myBuffer.allocate(sz);
    _p_vals=pBuffer; //Atributo de la clase.
    for (unsigned int i=0;i<sz;i++)
    {

        myBuffer.construct(&pBuffer[i],*other._p_vals+i);
    }

}
```

Mi duda el la siguiente, yo tengo un atributo privado que es `int * _p_vals` al cual asigno el `*pBuffer`. Pero para destruir la memoria necesito en el destructor hacer una llamada del tipo `myBuffer.deallocate()`, después de haber hecho un `destroy()` de cada elemento. La cuestión es que no tengo un atributo `std::allocator<int>` al que asignarle `myBuffer`. Me gustaría saber si habría alguna otra forma de destruirlo sin necesidad de crear dicho atributo en mi clase.

Comment: ¿Y si creas otro allocator en el destructor y usas ese para hacer el deallocate() ?

Comment: Acedo a través del puntero _p_vals, para acceso y todo lo demás lo hago a través del puntero. Pero para borrar zona de memorio no puedo que yo sepa. Por eso preguntaba.

Comment: Que no leí bien la pregunta, perdona :-)

Comment: Nada tranquilo con new y delete era más fácil, perp new inicializa los objetos y allocator no. Luego me ahorro tiempo e inicializaciones innecesarias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No necesitas mantener la instancia del `std::allocator`. No es necesario:

> The default allocator is stateless, that is, all instances of the given allocator are interchangeable, compare equal and can deallocate memory allocated by any other instance of the same allocator type.

Todas las instancias del `std::allocator` son *sin-estado* e intercambiables, (siempre y cuando sean del mismo tipo), por lo que basta con hacer:

```
ArrayWrapper::~ArrayWrapper( ) {
  if( _p_vals ) {
    std::allocator< int > all;
    all.deallocate( _p_vasl, número-de-elementos );
  }
}
```

Lo único que necesitas es conocer el número de elementos para los que reservaste memoria previamente.

Comment: Gracias es lo que necesitaba.

Comment: @Jcpardo Un placer :-)